# ASP.NET Code blocks are not supported in this context Site.master

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to write some code in my master page to check if a user is logged in. Here is the block of code

```
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <% 

                    if (Session["UserID"] == null) {
                    %>
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <%
                    } else  { 
                    %>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Session["UserID"] %>!</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code blocks like

```
<% if (Session["UserID"] == null) {
                %> ...
```

Are not allowed inside an `<asp: runat="server">`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked as soon as I changed that.